# Finding if there is a duplicate name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have the following;

```
<input type="text" id="1" name="1" value="" />
<input type="text" id="2" name="2" value="" />
<input type="text" id="3" name="3" value="" />
<input type="text" id="4" name="2" value="" />
```

I am trying to have a function that will be able to figure out if there is an attribute with the same name.

So for this example, a red flag will come up that `id="4"` has a duplicate name attribute.

I know I have to do something like this, but I may be beating around the bush here. What do you guys think?

```
function findDuplicates(name) {
    var found = 0;

    $("input").each(function() { 
         if($(this).attr('name') == name)
            found++;
    });

    return found;
}
```

Comment: If you're asking if there's something built into JS that does this, there is not.  You have to build a function yourself.  This isn't a very good question as it stands, as you've not shown what you've tried.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 what about what I have up there now? Can you see a more practical method of doing it or will that suffice?

Comment: Looks fine for a basic method to me.  I would create an array of jQuery objects though, the jQuery DOM access gets expensive when you do it in inner loops like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try jQuery attribute selector:

```
if(1 < $('input[name=2][type=text]').length) {
    //duplicate
}
```

So your function will look like:

```
function findDuplicates(name) {
    return $('input[name='+ name +']').length;
}
```

**EDIT**

With plain JS:

```
function findDuplicates(name) {
    return document.getElementsByName(name).length;
}
```

Comment: Just for completeness if somebody would want to do it without jQuery: `document.getElementsByName(name).length` would provide the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Make an empty div somewhere, let's say I've given my div an id of "return_value".

```
<script>
function validate(){
    var name1 = document.getElementById("1").value;
    var name2 = document.getElementById("2").value;
    var name3 = document.getElementById("3").value;
    var name4 = document.getElementById("4").value;

    var error = '';

    error = (name1 == name2 || name1 == name3 || name1 == name4 || name2 == name3 || name2 == name4 || name3 == name4) ? 'Duplicate Entry!' : 'Data OK!';

    getElementById("return_value").innerHTML = error;

}   
</script>
```

You just make your form onsubmit call the Javascript function to do the comparison,   if you want to actually submit the form if the data is valid, you can do that using AJAX.    Previous poster is correct in that it's difficult to answer this without more info on what specifically you are attempting to do.

Comment: while technically correct it's a terrible answer: it doesn't scale.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for a scaling solution.    He said "I have this" and listed 4 inputs.   A quick and dirty question gets a quick and dirty answer.

Comment: I appreciate the time, but it was just an example. Would definitely need it for any amount of elements. I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
var found = 0;
var array = new Array(); //create new array

$( "input[type=text]" ).each(function( index ) {
    var name = $(index).attr('name'); //get name of current element
    if(array.indexOf(name) == -1) //check if name doesn't exist in array
    {
      array.push(name); //if true, add it to the array
    } else {
      found++; //if it exists, increment found
      var duplicate = $(index).attr('id'); //get the id of the current element
      console.log('Input with Id = ' + duplicate + ' has a duplicate name attribute');
    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you minus 1 from the length you could return a 0 for no duplicates.

I'd also pass in the element and the attribute name for full reusability.

```
function hasDuplicates(el, attr, value) {
    return $(el + '[' + attr + '=' + value + ']').length - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers requires that you know the name of the attribute you are trying to find which doesn't make sense, if he knew the name of the input field he could just view source in the browser and see if 2 elements with the same name are found.

Use the following code, you can copy and paste it in your browser's console window:

```
var found = 0;
var array = new Array(); //create new array

$("input[type=text]").each(function( index ) {
    var name = $(index).attr('name'); //get name of current element
    if(array.indexOf(name) == -1) //check if name doesn't exist in array
    {
         array.push(name); //if true, add it to the array
    } else {
         found++; //if it exists, increment found
         var duplicate = $(index).attr('name'); //get the name of the duplicate element
         console.log('Input with Name => ' + duplicate + ' has a duplicate name attribute');
    }
});
```